# Can a context-free Language have an infinite pumping length?

Tags: pumping-lemma

I have a language that would require an infinite pumping length, I know the language is not context-free, but is this sufficient prove ?

Comment: A context free language always has a finite pumping length. What even is an infinite pumping length?

Comment: What I meant is a Language, which is infinite and for every word you would have to make the pumping length as large as the word itself. If that does not change your answer, my question has been solved, thank you

Comment: It does not change the answer. Basically what you have is a language $L$ such that $L^*=L$, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, sorry if my question was misleading

Comment: If you know the pumping length must be at least as long as the word itself, then use the pumping lemma to disprove this is context free: let $p$ be the *constant* pumping length, and then choose a word with length bigger than $p$ that you cannot "pump" (with this particular pumping length)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify what you are asking.  Please don't put clarifications in the comments -- instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters this for the first time.  Part of our mission is to build up a knowledge bank that will be useful to others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The pumping lemma for context-free languages states that if $L$ is context-free then there exists a constant $p$ such that each word $w \in L$ of length at least $p$ can be partitioned into $w = uxyzv$ such that the following properties hold:

- $|xz| > 0$.
- $|xyz| \le p$.
- For each $i \geq 0$, $w = ux^iyz^iv$.

In order to show that a language $L$ isn't context-free, we show that the property above doesn't hold for *any* $p$. That is, we show that for every *constant* $p$ there exists a word in $L$ of length at least $p$ which cannot be partitioned as above.

While the concept of *pumping length* is natural, it is not a standard one. One way to define it is as the minimal $p$ for which the consequence of the pumping lemma holds, if such a $p$ exists, or infinity otherwise. In these terms, the pumping lemma can be expressed succinctly as stating that context-free languages have finite pumping length. Equivalently, a language with infinite pumping length is not context-free.

The converse doesn't hold: some non-context-free languages have finite pumping length. In the case of regular languages, the pumping lemma can be strengthened to give an if-and-only-if condition, as was done by [Jaffe](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/990524.990528) and by [Stanat](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/1008892.1008895) (and possibly by others). To the best of my knowledge, no such strengthening exists for context-free languages, though stronger versions of the pumping lemma are known, for example [Ogden's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogden%27s_lemma) (which can be "backported" to regular languages).